# Convert JSONArray's to JSON Object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am trying to convert **two JSON arrays into a JSON object** which I read from ajax call. 
This is how I am reading and storing it **(Just showing this part of the code incase, you can jump to next paragraph)**:

```
        var a = []; 
        var b = [];

        var docsDatafromSOLR = response.response.docs;
        var lengthOfSOLR_response = docsDatafromSOLR.length;

        for (var i=0; i< lengthOfSOLR_response; i++) {
            a.push({
                latitude: docsDatafromSOLR[i].latitude,
                longitude: docsDatafromSOLR[i].longitude
            });

        }
```

So basically my array a should look like this, I've skipped the rest of the data:

```
       "a": [
        {
         "latitude": 23,
         "longitude":43
        },
         {
         "latitude":42,
         "longitude":67
         } 
      ]
```

Array b would be the same as well.

**Now the QUESTION is how do I make the above JSON arrays "a" and "b" to something like this below. I've searching for the syntax but found nothing useful.**

```
{
"1": {
    "a": {
        "latitude": "41",
        "longitude": "-73"
    },
    "b": {
        "latitude": "32",
        "longitude": "-29"
    }
},
"2": {
    "a": {
        "latitude": "47",
        "longitude": "-69"
    },
    "b": {
        "latitude": "42",
        "longitude": "-35"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You should add what you've tried so far/What is causing problems for you.

Comment: Those are actually not JSON arrays, but regular Javascript arrays. JSON is a way to encode / serialize / stringify Javascript data.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution I can think of is using [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Simply map one of the arrays to the expected result, e.g.

```
var result = a.map(function(location, index) { 
    return {a: location, b: b[index]}
});
```

Comment: it still stays as an array. copy pasted from console:[Object, Object, Object]
0: Object
a: 12
b: 11
__proto__: Object
1: Object
a: 23
b: 33
__proto__: Object
2: Object
a: 34
b: 44

Answer (score 1):

## try this:

```
var array1 = {
    "a": [
        {
            "latitude": 0,
            "longitude":0
        },
        {
            "latitude":5,
            "longitude":5
        } 
    ]
}

var array2 = {
    "b": [
        {
            "latitude": 10,
            "longitude":10
        },
        {
            "latitude":20,
            "longitude":20
        } 
    ]
}


var result = {}; 
var key1 = Object.keys(array1)[0];
var key2 = Object.keys(array2)[0]; 

for(var i=0; i<array1[key1].length; i++){  
    result[i] = {};
    result[i][key1] = array1[key1][i];
    result[i][key2] = array2[key2][i];
}


console.log(JSON.stringify(result,null,2));
```

## output:

```
{
  "0": {
    "a": {
      "latitude": 0,
      "longitude": 0
    },
    "b": {
      "latitude": 10,
      "longitude": 10
    }
  },
  "1": {
    "a": {
      "latitude": 5,
      "longitude": 5
    },
    "b": {
      "latitude": 20,
      "longitude": 20
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda hard to figure out exactly where this would go but try [parsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) out your returned data from your ajax call like so.

```
.done(function (data) {
    JSON.parse(data); //If properly formatted in your response, data should now be formatted as a object.
})
```